# Flurry integration build fails: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, flurry

I dragged the Flurry.h and libFlurry.a to my project. Added the neccessary inovation in my main delgate with a correct key. I already had the SystemsConfigurations.framework in my project. When buildin I get the follow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KitzyAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have checked other build issues on Stackoverflow and nothing worked. Flurry's document is pretty lacking in details and problem solving.

Stackoverflow Lords please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the Flurry SDK version being used by you? Also, have you added all of the required frameworks: 
MediaPlayer.framework, 
SystemConfiguration.framework, 
UIKit.framework, 
CoreGraphics.framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue, users need to refer to the readMe .pdf with the zip file as you need to move the sdk folder with the two files into your xcode project.